# Sending an object to a service hosting a MemoryCache using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, tcp, memorycache

I'm tinkering around with WCF and MemoryCache. The goal is to host WCF in a Windows Service so  different clients can access this cache.

The first part, setting up the host works fine and I'm able to write to and read from the cache via a separate client application. At least, when trying to put very simple objects in the cache, like a string or a value type like int.

When I try a 'custom' object, even if it only has a string property, stuff starts to go wrong:

```
There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:value. 

TheInnerException message was 'Type 'Solution.MyType' with data contract name 
'MyType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyType' is not expected. 
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list    
of known types 
- for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by 
adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.
Please see   InnerException for more details.
```

Now after some searching I found that I might had to decorate my type with a KnownType attribute, but alas, with no succes. I also tried decorating it with DataContract and DataMember attributes, but no sigar either.

What to do now? Isn't the WCF DataContractResolver supposed to do this work for me? I find it hard to believe I'd have to write a custom DataContractResolver for every class I want to have serialized. What else are the DataContract and DataMember attributes for?

What am I missing here? Note also that MyType does not inherit from another class (save object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by implementing some custom serialisation:

```
string result = string.Empty;
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyType));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, encoding, true))
        {
            ser.WriteObject(writer, principal);
            writer.Flush();
            result = encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```

which suffices for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried marking MyType with the Serizlizable marker?  Check out '[Designing Service Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx)' in the MSDN library for how to properly create the service.  Also, post some of your code from the service and the implementing class.

Comment: Yeah, I have, although just having DataContract should be enough isn't? Either way it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to deal with one of the funniest parts of WCF taht is the KnownType, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx, basically you need to specify the [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) for each 'child' type you need to serialize, even if they are marked as serializable.

Comment: MyType doesn't inherit from anything, save object itself and only contains a property of type string. And although I have tried to add this a KnownType attribute, it left me with exactly the same error.
Might using a net.tcp binding instead of a basicHttpBinding have anything to do with this?

Comment: Sorry I misused the 'child', I mean any property type of the 'main' object you are trying to serialize.